Converting robot framework file into independent executable file
I have a test.robot file , I want to convert it to test.exe file that can run indpendently on any windows machine without the need to install any other depedencies like python or robotframework.
I tried pyinstaller using command pyinstaller --onefile test.robot.
that will result an executable file test.exe.
when I try to run it, I face this error
 [ ERROR ] Importing library 'robot.libraries.BuiltIn' failed: Module 'robot.libraries' does not contain 'BuiltIn'.

any help how can I solve the above error, or is there any other straight forward suggestion to achive my aim.

it may means pyinstalle couldn't find some module (or C/C++ library) and it didn't add it to .exe. And it may need to use file spec to add this element manually - Using Spec Files — PyInstaller 6.6.0 documentation. Did you search if someone else already had this problem?

"file that can run indpendently on any windows machine without the need to install any other depedencies like python or robotframework." - I guess Docker is your friend in this case. You can create a Docker image and with that, it is possible to run Robot tests on any machine. Check out this page that shows Docker Images for Robot Framework.

docker image is good option , but still you need to add docker desktop to the machine, right?  @Pramesh

I didnt see similar problem @furas

I found forum robotframework - maybe there are people which better know this framework.

I was working on something similar where I had to make an exe file for an automated task written in robot framework (reason - I wanted to avoid the user seeing the source code). I was searching for an answer, I came across this question earlier, but I saw no concrete answer to this question here, so I came back to share what I did.

I tried to convert the .robot file to an exe using pyinstaller directly. But I was getting the following error:
*** Settings *** SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I converted everything in .robot file to python. (and then used code obfuscation tools before making an exe).

I got the same error while trying to convert the python file to .exe. Turns out, pyinstaller cannot always automatically include all the used libraries in your code in the .exe file it is trying to generate.

[ ERROR ] Importing library 'robot.libraries.BuiltIn' failed: Module 'robot.libraries' does not contain 'BuiltIn'.

Possible solutions to your problem -

Include "--hidden-import=robot.libraries.BuiltIn" in the command you are using.


pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=robot.libraries.BuiltIn
test.robot
2. If the above command doesn't work for you (didn't work in my case, because  robot.libraries.BuiltIn module uses some other modules internally which pyinstaller was not including in the .exe automatically) and it gives similar error but for other libraries (for me, I got same error with Easter and Reserved libraries after step 1), check the path to the library and include that in --hidden-import option, as follows:
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=robot.libraries.BuiltIn --hidden-import=robot.libraries.Easter --hidden-import=robot.libraries.Reserved test.robot

Also, it is worth noting that, Pyinstaller will not add/import non python files to the exe automatically until you specify. Robot framework uses some not python files in "pythonpath\Lib\site-packages\robot\htmldata" folder and its subfolders to generate the log files. So, you need to specify that too while creating the exe.

pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "yourPythonPath\Lib\site-packages\robot\htmldata;robot\htmldata" --hidden-import=robot.libraries.BuiltIn --hidden-import=robot.libraries.Easter --hidden-import=robot.libraries.Reserved test.robot

After all this, if you are still not able to convert the .robot file to .exe directly, you can write a python wrapper script that will use Robot Framework's API to execute the .robot test suite. Then, you can try converting the .py file to exe while keeping the .robot file in exe by adding --add-data "test.robot;." option in the command (including the required hidden imports).
If you are still unable to generate the exe, you can then try converting the whole thing to python.
